# Java Input Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, user-input

I'm currently developing a project where, at several points, the user will receive question prompts that must be answered through a keyboard input, each answer being atributed to a variable in order to call for the appropriate next step. The first part has three questions, and the variables associated with them are String - Int - String types. Afterwards, the program displays the informations via a print function. However, upon testing the first round of prompts to be asked, I noted three things:

1. Upon inputing a two worded name as the answer for the first input prompt, the console stops running the code altogether, with the next prompt displaying the following error message:
   Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943) at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598) at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2263) at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2217) at geradorfichasrpg/geradorfichasrpg.FichaPC.ID_PC(FichaPC.java:23) at geradorfichasrpg/geradorfichasrpg.FichaPC.main(FichaPC.java:11)
2. A single word works just fine and the console continues running the code as expected;
3. The last input does accept a two worded answer, but only the first word is displayed and the console stops running the code (but with no error message this time).

What's wrong? The code is right bellow.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FichaPC {
    public static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("= Character Sheet Generator (D&D 5th Edition) =");
        System.out.println("");
        
        ID_PC();
        }

    
    public static void ID_PC() {
        String name = "";
        int age = 0;
        String align = "";
        
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        name = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Alignment: ");
        align = keyboard.next();
        
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        System.out.println(age);
        System.out.print("Align: ");
        System.out.println(align);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, simply replacing `next()` with `nextLine()` will cause different issues. See [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: It does! Thanks a lot.